# If DriverManager.getConnection(url, info) returns same connection, is it a leak?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, memory-leaks

We use oracle JDBC, if call

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
logger.debug("(open connection):[" + connection + "]");
```

return a connection (i.e.`oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5dux6a69`) which has be generated before (from log `5dux6a69` show up before), just like

```
2016-03-02 18:26:13,126 -- DEBUG -- com.myapp.module.loadData -- [user]  (open connection):[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5dux6a69]
....
2016-03-02 18:40:15,900 -- DEBUG -- com.myapp.module.loadData -- [user]  (open connection):[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5dux6a69]
```

is it a sign of connection leak?

Comment: There's no way we can possibly answer that without seeing your code or knowing anything about your connection pool. Are you closing/returning connections? Have you queried the number of connections?

Comment: @Andrew Regan Actually I just want to ask any oracle jdbc can return the a connection with same name, if very very little chance then it indicates a loose end or not..

Comment: Maybe someone has an authoritative answer, but I don't think you should assume that the `T4CConnection` is necessarily a / the same physical connection. Also we can't see what any pool is doing. It might look odd, but I don't think what you've seen necessarily proves anything.

Comment: @Andrew Regan Just update the post, showing two line of logs, is it give any idea? It is a JDBC connection, no JNDI etc

Comment: As @AndrewRegan has stated, it is impossible to tell. The same Java `Connection` object might be using a different TCP connection. `netstat` would tell you more, if you ran it during the first and second connections respectively. It might also be using the same connection. There might be connection pooling behind the scenes. `netstat` will show you any connection leaks.

Comment: How do you know for sure it is the same connection, they might just have the same hashcode.

Comment: @AndrewRegan JDBC drivers usually don't provide connection pooling from `DriverManager.getConnection` (a quick scan of a decompiled Oracle driver seems to confirm that it doesn't).

Comment: +1 for decompiling the JAR, I couldn't find the source anywhere. Though I still think we should prefer authoritative ways of tracking connections and leaks.